# Create columns from json format text

Tags: parsing, kql

Is there anyway I can get the following to work without using the "parse" function? My input contains a field with delimited text, where there is a column name followed by "=" and then the value. I would like to create a column named with what precedes the = and insert what is afterwards as the value.

```
let Traces = datatable(EventText:string)
[
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=23, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:01)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=15, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:00, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:00, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:00)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=20, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:01)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=22, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:41:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:41:00, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=16, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:41:00, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:41:00, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:00)"
];
Traces
| project data = replace_string(extract(@"\(([^\)]+)", 1, EventText), "=", ":")
| extend data = parse_json(data)
| evaluate bag_unpack(data)
```

Comment: Do you mean the `parse` operator? Do you have something against it?

Comment: :) I guess you could apply the same or a similar strategy with the "parse" operator.

Comment: If you have a fixed pattern (same key-value pairs, in the same order), then the `parse` operator is a great match and the solution becomes much simpler.

Comment: I can see that. My issue are tables with a varied number of entities and I need to do exploratory data analysis. Your solution is awesome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some regex (there multiple variations on this) + [mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) + [bag_unpack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin) plugin

P.S.
Those timestamps are painful to watch.
I see no reason to use anything else but the ISO formats.

```
let Traces = datatable(EventText:string)
[
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=23, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:01)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=15, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:00, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:00, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:00)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=20, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:01)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=22, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:41:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:41:00, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=16, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:41:00, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:41:00, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:00)"
];
Traces
| project   kv = extract_all(@"(\w+?)=([^,)]*)", EventText)
| mv-apply  kv on (summarize kv = make_bag(bag_pack(tostring(kv[0]), kv[1])))
| evaluate  bag_unpack(kv)
```

| lockTime | previousLockTime | releaseTime | resourceName | sliceNumber | totalSlices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/17/2016 08:40:01 | 02/17/2016 08:39:01 | 02/17/2016 08:40:01 | PipelineScheduler | 23 | 27 |
| 02/17/2016 08:40:00 | 02/17/2016 08:39:00 | 02/17/2016 08:40:00 | PipelineScheduler | 15 | 27 |
| 02/17/2016 08:40:01 | 02/17/2016 08:39:01 | 02/17/2016 08:40:01 | PipelineScheduler | 20 | 27 |
| 02/17/2016 08:41:01 | 02/17/2016 08:40:01 | 02/17/2016 08:41:00 | PipelineScheduler | 22 | 27 |
| 02/17/2016 08:41:00 | 02/17/2016 08:40:00 | 02/17/2016 08:41:00 | PipelineScheduler | 16 | 27 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA9WUPU/DMBCG90j5D6dONgTVCdBCUAQLG6oQ7RZC5aZHMXHiyHYCRfx43ERioh9LB2RZsuz3PevxnU+ihZnmORpIYMmtGwuJ5L7Fys7w08bGalGtqO+lvjfotmOYKCte11MpcnxCidwgEI1GNTrHCS8xeRQ1SlHhNH/DZSNRB2CV5bKzmCQaB2A2y0lTLlAn0XkAUuXFTDgvi4bheBixcATsKr5gMQsD0P012wW1xlaoxjz8Heb82qnoIDgeQ3i5k4HtY2AHMbCjMkTs/+chirYzhPsYwkPy0JEet5ZGOxl219LBDK6WfC+78b3+//vet3Opd8wtABSt6wfu/7sjO+dSkrsBef44vaUJSV8Cmp24B4DfLkE35rI943Ut151ZVUBMU5Zciy/so5W8wPmCr4ib85rnBbGq7y6kaFOW0cDp0jCjtAuHLZcNtwiw0TdV5yha+gOK3sbgsgQAAA==)